# How to Deal with Warping Textures in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

First time posting here. New to Blender as well. Thanks in advance for any help!

I'm trying to render an image of a lamp in cycles and I'm using nodes to apply the image texture to a transparent cylinder with a light inside of it. Where I'm stuck is I can't get the image texture to scale properly on the cylinder.

The texture image is made up of colored squares, but as you can see in the rendered image, there's this weird warping going on. The Z values on the mapping node are to get the texture properly aligned vertically on the column. But no matter what I set the X and Y to, I can't get just squares all the way across the cylinder.

Trying to figure out how to upload the blender file....

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Here's the next step. I was able to get the image corrected using uv unwrapping. The preview render looks good but when I run the final render I get this weird doubling through part of the image. I cannot for the life of me figure out what's causing that.

Sample Render (good):
[image]

Actual Render (weird doubling of image):
[image]
[image]

With some great help, I've gotten this far! (see below) My last question for this thread is about the image texture looking soft. The image file itself is 2257 x 2440 pixels.

[image]

I used the same image texture to render in Adobe Dimension:

[image]

It may have to do with mapping it to a transparency shader?

Here's the updated file:
[image]

Comment: You need to mark seams, uv unwrap your object,  and use UV coordinates not object coordinates in texture coordinates input node. Blend files can be uploaded to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Add the resulting link to your question as an [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/114952/edit) rather than using the comments.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I was able to do that successfully, but am getting a weird effect in the image now (see above). Blender file posted if anyone has time to take a look.

Comment: Change the order of your modifiers (your subsurf is set to 0 in viewport but 2 in render, thats why you dont see it),  Subsurf first, solidify second

Comment: Hi, thanks Johan. I never would have figured that out. I've posted an updated render and blender file. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to get the texture to be sharper? Also, how do I mark Timaroberts reply as the answer to this thread?